# Differentiate between color Resource Id and int color

Tags: java, android, colors, drawable

I have a method that should return a `Drawable` object. It takes Int color or color ResourceId as a parameter, the method should check whether the passed parameter is a ResourceId or Int color

```
public Drawable getDrawable(int colorIntOrResId){
  if(isItaResColorId(colorIntOrResId)){ //for ex. R.color.white is an int
       return context.getDrawable(isItaResColorId);
  }
 else if(isItIntColor(colorIntOrResId)){ // for ex. Color.parseColor("#ffffff") is also an int
      return new ColorDrawable(isItIntColor)
   }
}
```

**In Short**: `R.color.white` and `Color.parseColor("white")` Both returns `Integer` values, How I can programmatically check whether that Integer is a color `ResId` or a `Int color`